# How to access widget's properties in transformation of a page type

Tags: widget, transformation, web-parts, kentico

I have created a widget which have some properties in Kentico. I want to access  the value of that property in a transformation. Is there a way... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the widget properties directly, but you can achieve this by get set webpart properties and then register your webpart as a widget.

Refer this [link](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/how-to-get-and-set-a-web-part-property-value-in-a-transformation)

Thanks

Happy to help!